# Multiple Search and cut RegEx in TextPad

Tags: search, find, textpad

Is there a Regex that could cut multiple lines from a document based on multiple searches.

I want to be able to enter a list of figures and cut the whole lines e.g

I want to search and Cut lines containing 27761379, 27761380, 27761381, 27761382 from data looking like this.

```
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/101/28/00000000000000010128.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/101/35/00000000000000010135.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/101/64/00000000000000010164.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/101/65/00000000000000010165.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/101/86/00000000000000010186.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/165/60/00000000000000016560.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/182/25/00000000000000018225.xml
4093115/000/000/000/000/000/182/26/00000000000000018226.xml
```

Any help you could give on this would be greatly appreciated as its very time consuming at the moment to working on a line by line basis.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Stack Overflow is website about programming.  Sorry, but this question is out of place here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the following:

1. Press F5 to search, and use the following regex: `^.*277613[79|80|81|82].*$`
2. Click `Mark All` on the search dialog
   [image: TextPad Search Dialog]
3. It will mark those lines (look at the little blue arrows on the left - these are `bookmarks`. You can now perform actions on these bookmarks, such as cutting them:

[image: Cutting bookmarked lines in TextPad]